# Why does Spark Streaming execute foreachRDD even when no new data is available?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have the following Spark streaming example:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Name").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

val directoryStream = ssc.textFileStream("""file:///C:/Users/something/something""")
directoryStream.foreachRDD(file => {
  println(file.count())
})

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Even when the folder is empty it keeps printing 0 every 2 seconds like if an empty file was in the folder. I would like it to only go into the `foreachRDD` when a new file is present in the folder. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I am using Spark 1.6 and Scala 2.10.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your batch duration is 2 seconds the job will trigger for each and every 2 seconds, basically the triggering point is not the data availability it is batch duration, if the data present at the time the DStream contains the data otherwise it will be empty ( use below code to check for the same)

```
 dstream.foreachRDD{ rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty) {// do something } }
```

Comment: I see, thank you for that easy solution. Now I'm wondering, if lets say two text files come up within the 2 second window, are they joined together into one iteration of `foreachRDD` ? Or will Spark run two iterations of `foreachRDD` at that time?

Comment: One RDD at a batch so two text files "unioned" together.